# Round and Remove 3 digits Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following Dataframe:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDKoC.png)

```
print (df)
               time
0  00:00:04.4052727
1     00:00:06.5798
```

and my goal is to round the microseconds to 2 digits and remove the other digits so there are only 2 digits.

All columns should then look like the first row:

```
print (df)
           time
0  00:00:04.405
1  00:00:06.580
```

Comment: Do you need `df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('100L').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove last 3 digits (`000`) after convert values to `HH:MM:SS.fffff` format:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])


df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('100L').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
print (df)
           time
0  00:00:04.400
1  00:00:06.600
```

Another idea is round by 1 milisecond:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('1ms')
print (df)
                     time
0 2022-12-12 00:00:04.405
1 2022-12-12 00:00:06.580


df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('1ms').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
print (df)
           time
0  00:00:04.405
1  00:00:06.580
```

If need only truncate values use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.floor('1ms')

print (df)
                     time
0 2022-12-12 00:00:04.405
1 2022-12-12 00:00:06.579


df['time'] = df['time'].dt.floor('1ms').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
print (df)
           time
0  00:00:04.405
1  00:00:06.579
```